# Android Q: Starting activity from background task on Android 10 from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-10.0

According to Android 10 documentation I should be able to start an activity from a BroadcastReciver following a `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`, and I can indeed! hurray! But what about `CALL_STATE_RINGING` or `OFFHOOK`, why does it not work then? Can I only do this for outgoing calls but not for incoming calls?

The documentation is missing the complete list of states in which you can resume an activity following a Broadcastreciver firing so am stuck on this.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: "Can I only do this for outgoing calls but not for incoming calls?" -- I would assume that statement is correct. Show a high-priority notification will an associated full-screen `Intent` instead.

Comment: I need to launch a UI without requiring the user to tap on a notification, I don't get why you would be able to do this for outgoing but not incoming calls. If I can't figure it out I will have no choice but to use notifications as you suggest. I do wish it was clearer in the documentation.

Comment: "I don't get why you would be able to do this for outgoing but not incoming calls" -- most outgoing calls are user-initiated. So, the user tapped something for an outgoing call, and then the screen appears. By contrast, mot incoming calls are not user-initiated. They happen when they happen. Starting full-screen activities from the background interrupts whatever the user is doing, which may be more important than the call (e.g., driving and relying on a navigation app). So, I am not surprised that there is a difference here.

Comment: I hadn't considered it that way, the driving scenario is a good example. I wonder what happens on an iPhone where when you have an incoming call it interrupts everything and you're not allowed to leave until you action the call, hmmm, anyway thanks for your response. I will use notifications for incoming calls.